# Blank Android Studio window in DWM

Tags: x11, xorg, window-manager, dwm, intellij

I recently installed Android Studio on arch linux with DWM. But the initial dialog window, which prompts for starting a new project is blank. The links in this windows work though. I can start a new project by blindly clicking where the new project button is supposed to be. There is no problem with the new project wizard, but the editor window which loads up is blank as well.

However, if I start the X server with android studio as the client, It works correctly. So it's an issue with DWM. What could be the reason?

Edit:

Intellij has the same problem with dwm.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Non-reparenting_window_managers

Comment: Thanks, setting the variable works but I've run on another issue. I can't set the variable from `.xinitrc`. These are the last two lines of my `.xinitrc`:      `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
exec $1`. It works if I set the variable in shell startup file

Comment: It should work in `.xinitrc`, but equally will work in your shell profile.

Comment: yes it should, but it doesn't. That's the problem, I can't export variables from `.xinitrc`

Comment: That is a separate issue. Just put it in your shell profile.

Answer (score 22):

You'll need to set the **_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING** variable to **1** through some way to Android Studio.

If you're starting `dwm` via `startx`, add this to your `.xinitrc`:

```
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

If you're launching Android Studio from a shell, add the same line to your shell's rc file.

If you're launching Android Studio from a shortcut, and you're not using `startx`, then you'll have to [add the variable to the WM after the process started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/211064).

Comment: Report from the future: the solution works also in ratpoison.

Comment: My session starts `dwm` from `gdm3`, which calls `~/.Xsession` so there is where the export have to be in this case. Previously using `startx` and yes, `~/.xinitrc` is the way. Or `~/.xsessionrc` (Debian and derivatives specific)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working with `_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1` and starting android-studio from command line.

android-studio also needs sudo to install components if your android-sdk install is in default from AUR (`/opt/android-sdk`) and if thats the case just start android-studio with:

```
sudo _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 android-studio
```

Just added that as an alias in rofi and good to go :)