# Gnome - Android Studio completely blank screen on Centos 7

Tags: centos, x11, gnome

I installed Android Studio to my CentOS 7 (7.6.1810)

When I open android-studio, all I am getting is blank screen as can bee seen in the screenshot below;

[image]

I have tried many thing to fix this issue such as applying these [suggestions.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368817/blank-android-studio-window-in-dwm) But none of them worked.

Here are the information about GUI;

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=24115
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
GUESTFISH_INIT=\e[1;34m
HOSTNAME=*****
XRDP_SOCKET_PATH=/tmp/.xrdp
IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP=yes
VTE_VERSION=5202
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
HISTSIZE=1000
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/2a009749_456f_4a0e_b235_bf414ccd516a
IMSETTINGS_MODULE=none
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.100
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/0/keyring/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/23903,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/23903
XRDP_PULSE_SINK_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_10
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
GUESTFISH_PS1=\[\e[1;32m\]><fs>\[\e[0;31m\] 
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=classic
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
PWD=/root
XMODIFIERS=@im=none
XRDP_SESSION=1
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XRDP_PULSE_SOURCE_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_10
GUESTFISH_OUTPUT=\e[0m
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
_JAWA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
LOGNAME=root
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/root/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-KCxLOcDQEB,guid=acae1f9a0c4315a6e1c3b6785c67d39e
UID=0
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
DISPLAY=:10.0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
GTK_IM_MODULE=gtk-im-context-simple
GUESTFISH_RESTORE=\e[0m
COLORTERM=truecolor
```

I am pretty sure I installed it properly since I have installed it many times on many linux OS's before.

Any suggestions are highly welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you disabled SELinux? This could cause the trouble! Or this  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368817/blank-android-studio-window-in-dwm + make sure JAVA_HOME env var is set, too.

Comment: Hi @MichaelD. Yes I have tried disabling SELinux, also tried everything on this link. I double checked everthing including `JAVA_HOME` but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `xrdp` with CentOS 7 or above try

- editing `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` and
- changing to `max_bpp=24`

It worked for me.