# Centos 7 XRDP Android Studio Blank Screen

Tags: centos, x11, gnome, kde, xrdp

It's similar to this question: [Gnome - Android Studio completely blank screen on Centos 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501052/gnome-android-studio-completely-blank-screen-on-centos-7/517741?noredirect=1#comment956714_517741).

I have tried GNOME & KDE two different desktop env to open XRDP session, but got the same result.

I process android studio: `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

[image: Android Stuido Blank Window]

I also tried AOSP emulator but also got a blank window.
[image: AOSP Emulator Blank Window]

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. found solution [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000675024-Blank-configuration-window-). 
John Hagen: For me, this issue was an XRDP issue, fixed in CentOS 7.6 by editing /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini and changing to max_bpp=24.

don't forget restart